# How to stop the onLocationChanged() in my LocationListener

Tags: locationlistener

How to stop the  onLocationChanged() in my   LocationListener , when i press the button ,the Toastbox in onLocationChanged keep coming out and can not stop even i leave the application.

```
Button btn_location =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
btn_location.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) { 


               LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
               LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(); 
               mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener); 
        }

    });

 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener     {  


            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)       
            {   

                loc.getLatitude();         
                loc.getLongitude();          
                String Text = "My current location is: " +         "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +         "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();          
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
             }        
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)       
            {         
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();       
             }        
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)       
            {         
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
             }        
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)       
            {        

            }     
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply this:

mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);

to a button or put in onDestroy() or onPause()

Ref:[Android Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    aLocationManager.removeUpdates(aLocationListener);
}
```

Just call removeUpdates() method wherever you want to stop update!